# What exactly are the differences between semantic and lexical-semantic networks?

Tags: terminology, definitions, semantics

What exactly are the differences between *semantic* and *lexical-semantic* networks?

Answer (score 1):

According to **Wikipedia**  and 
[Semantic Networks](http://www.jfsowa.com/pubs/semnet.htm)
 ,By John F. Sowa
This is an updated version of an article in the Encyclopedia of Artificial Intelligence, Wiley, 1987, second edition, 1992.

> A semantic network is used when one has knowledge that is best
>   understood as a set of concepts that are related to one another.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_network#Basics_of_semantic_networks):

> Most semantic networks are cognitively based. They also consist of arcs and nodes which can be organized into a taxonomic hierarchy. Semantic networks contributed ideas of [spreading activation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreading_activation), inheritance, and nodes as proto-objects.

An example of semantic network is [WordNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet). It groups English words into [synsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonym_ring). Some semantic relations between these synsets are meronymy, hyponymy, etc.

On the other hand, [**Lexical semantic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_semantics#Semantic_networks):

> ...explores whether the meaning of a lexical unit is established by looking at its neighborhood in the [semantic net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_network) (words it occurs with in natural sentences), or whether the meaning is already locally contained in the lexical unit.

Answer (score 1):

"semantic network" is way of representing "semantic" relations in form of a "graph" . where as "lexical semantic network" is a type of semantic network which represents the relations between words , sub-words or some-other linguistic related terms. so in other words , lexical semantic networks are a type of semantic networks dealing with language relationships.

Comment: would you mind if I add links in this answer to [Semantic network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_network) and [Lexical semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_semantics)?  *(Reviewing your concise synopsis of the concepts, there doesn't seem to be any conflict with the wikis, but wanted to run it by you for approval.)*